# Expression to colour font

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I've used the following expression to change the colour of my font, its working to an extent apart from values that are zero, which are remaining black.

```
=Switch(
Fields!Colour.Value="Orange","#ff8812" ,Fields!Colour.Value="Blue","Blue" ,  Fields!Colour.Value="Green","Green" ,Fields!Colour.Value="Red" ,"Red" ,true,"No color")
```

Comment: You could pick any color and then write an expression to control the `Visibility` to hide the 0's.

Answer (score 3):

"No Color" isn't a valid value for fonts.

[image: NoColour]

Answer (score 0):

Just add your expression as the color